# Fetching multiple pages from an API and adding to stream sink

Tags: flutter, dart, stream-builder

I'm fetching this API https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character and putting the data inside a Stream so I can infinite scroll over a Gridview of Cards with every character.
Fetching the first page with a `FutureBuilder` it works, but trying to use a `StreamBuilder` just doesn't update anything as if it wasn't receiving any data.

Here's the the `Provider.dart`

```
class CharacterProvider {
  final _url = 'rickandmortyapi.com';
  final _characterStream = StreamController<List<Character>>.broadcast();
  List<Character> _characters = [];
  int currentPage = 1;

  Function(List<Character>) get characterSink => _characterStream.sink.add;
  Stream<List<Character>> get characterStream => _characterStream.stream;

  void dispose() {
    _characterStream?.close();
  }

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> fetchData(
      String path, Map<String, dynamic> header) async {
    print(header);
    final response = await http.get(
      Uri.https(_url, 'api/$path', header),
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final results = jsonDecode(response.body);
      return results;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Fallo al cargar personajes');
    }
  }

  Future<List<Character>> fetchCharacters() async {
    final path = 'character';
    final header = {
      'page': currentPage.toString(),
    };
    final data = await fetchData(path, header);
    final characterFetched = Characters.fromJsonList(data['results']);
    _characters.addAll(characterFetched.character);
    characterSink(_characters);
    if (currentPage < data['info']['pages']) {
      currentPage++;
    }
    return characterFetched.character;
  }
}
```

The stream of `StreamBuilder` in the widget is subscribed to `characterStream` but it is always on null.

```
class _CharacterCardsState extends State<CharacterCards> {
  final _scrollController = ScrollController();
  Future<List<Character>> _characters;
  int cards;
  bool loading;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print('Cards: init');
    _characters = initFetch();
    loading = true;
    cards = 6;
    _scrollController.addListener(updateCards);
  }

Future<List<Character>> initFetch() async {
    final fetch = await CharacterProvider().fetchCharacters();
    return fetch;
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CharacterProvider().fetchCharacters();
    print('Cards: build');
    return GridView.builder(
        itemCount: cards,
        controller: _scrollController,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return StreamBuilder(
            stream: CharacterProvider().characterStream,
            builder: (BuildContext context,
                AsyncSnapshot<List<Character>> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                loading = false;
                final character = snapshot.data;
                return GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    cardView(context, character, index);
                  },
                  child: ofCard(character, index),
                );
              } else {
                return ofLoading(widget.size);
              }
            },
          );
        });
  }
```

On debug, the values added to the sink are non-null. The data is fetching correctly but the sink.add() doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're trying to use provider package (that's why you named your class `CharacterProvider()` I think), either way the problem is you're not saving a reference of that class, you're creating them anew each time you call `CharacterProvider().someMethod` so the initFetch `CharacterProvider().fetchCharacters()` and the stream `CharacterProvider().characterStream` are not related

Just like your scrollController you should create a `final characterProvider = CharacterProvider()` and call it in all your methods that requires it

PS: don't call a future `CharacterProvider().fetchCharacters();` inside build like that, it's an antipattern

Comment: It was indeed the case, using `final characterProvider = CharacterProvider()` did the job. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```dart
class _CharacterCardsState extends State<CharacterCards> {
  final _scrollController = ScrollController();
  Future<List<Character>> _characters;
  int cards;
  bool loading;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _characters = CharacterProvider();
    _characters.fetchCharacters();
    loading = true;
    cards = 6;
    _scrollController.addListener(updateCards);
  }

@override
void dispose(){
_characters.dispose();
super.dispose();
}


@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.builder(
        itemCount: cards,
        controller: _scrollController,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return StreamBuilder(
            stream: _characters.characterStream,
            builder: (BuildContext context,
                AsyncSnapshot<List<Character>> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                setState(()=>loading=false);
                final character = snapshot.data;
                return GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    cardView(context, character, index);
                  },
                  child: ofCard(character, index),
                );
              } else {
                return ofLoading(widget.size);
              }
            },
          );
        });
  }
```

I don't know why you are putting streambuilder inside gridview but logically above code should work.